# Generate customized static swagger documentation

Tags: html, css, reactjs, swagger

I have a swagger.yaml/.json file with documentation about my API. Now I want to generate static file from it. But I would like to customized it more than change color of Button. E.g. I want to change place where the button is or how big it is. After that I would like to get index.html as one file.

I've found something like `redoc-cli` or `swagger-codegen` but non of it helps me with my problem. I can only chose 'theme'. Is there any kind of tools which helps me with this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "customized static Swagger documentation"? Do you want to customize [Swagger UI](https://petstore.swagger.io)? Or customize [ReDoc](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/)? Or customize HTML docs generated by Swagger Codegen's `html` / `html2` / `dynamic-html` generators? Or create your own documentation renderer from scratch?

Comment: @Helen I want customized HTML dosc generated from swagger yaml file

Comment: _"generated from swagger yaml file"_ - generated by _which tool_ out of those I mentioned above?

Comment: @Helen By ReDoc

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags work in swagger .yaml/.json file, so actually you can create almost any design you want inside swagger file (not only openapi syntax works for designing documentation).

The final visible output depends on the environment and how do you plan to use the swagger file.

Comment: have you example somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I usually look for examples on swagger search page. Create free swagger account, login and search through existing APIs, there should be some user api's with HTML as well.